# How to run another controller's create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

I am working on the backend of a iphone application with rails. This is my first real project with rails.

This app is kind of a project management app. In the app it is possible for people to create a user account and at the same time they can choose to create a first project. So when users submit their information, my users controller receives a post request with params containing both the user info and the project info.

So what I am doing now is storing the user info with all attributes inside the database but I also check if the params contains any project info, and if it does I want to run the project controller's create action.

I know that this can be done by running two separate post requests or by making associations between the user model and the project model and then just run Project.create from the user controller but since I think this way essentially duplicates what a project create action should do anyway, I instead want to stay dry and just somehow run the projects controller's create action.

Is this possible in rails?, it is at least possible with php and zend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got code that is to be shared between controllers, you probably want to look to extracting it to a module and "mixing it in" as an include.

```
module SkyBlue
  def make_blue
   @my_colour = "blue"
  end
end

class Foo
  include SkyBlue

  def initialize
    @my_colour = "Foo coloured"
  end

  def my_colour
    @my_colour
  end
end

class Bar
  include SkyBlue

  def initialize
    @my_colour = "Bar coloured"
  end

  def my_colour
    @my_colour
  end
end
```

Then you can see the effect of the "mixed-in" module:

```
f = Foo.new
f.my_colour # => "Foo coloured"
f.make_blue
f.my_colour # => "blue"

b = Bar.new
b.my_colour # => "Bar coloured"
b.make_blue
b.my_colour # => "blue"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do that.

Skinny controller means that the code of controller actions' should be small.

Using various controller actions is possible and indeed may make you particular action's code small, but there is a tradeoff. You are increasing Coupling. You are making an action's code dependant of another controller.

Never do that. If you controller need to do something that is also done by other controller, that is OK. Think of actions like use cases, but might have similar, but they might be not related.

Just abstract to a helper method what makes sense to abstract.

Answer (score -1):

Just try calling it via `ControllerName.new(env).create` and see what happens ;-)